# How to get array value in post?

Tags: array

We have develop own module for wedding planner. We post multiple products with description on form submit. How to get the "wedding" array in the below values.

```
Array
(
    [weeding] => Array
        (
            [pCategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -1
                    [1] => 45
                )

            [product_cat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 14
                )

            [product_cat_input] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23423
                    [1] => 
                )

            [product_qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 24
                    [1] => 23423
                )

            [product_description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 234
                    [1] => 234
                )

            [metal_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23
                    [1] => 234
                )

            [stone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2423423
                    [1] => 234
                )

            [weight] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23
                    [1] => 23
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23
                    [1] => 23
                )

        )

    [fromprice] => 2
    [toprice] => 23
    [description] => 234
    [name] => vijay Kumar
    [email] => test@test.com
    [address] => Address
    [telephone] => 89
    [country] => IN
    [region_id] => 
    [region] => tamilnadu
    [city] => chennai
    [postcode] => 641029
)
```

We tried the below line. but this get all the value of post.

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getParams('wedding');
```

Please advice for this.

Comment: Is this a typo '[weeding] => Array'

Comment: @tecjam<please put this as answer

Comment: @Amit: I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem, or just a typo when creating the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be: `$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('wedding');`

If you use getParams() it returns the entire $_POST

Checkout class: Zend_Controller_Request_Http to see all the different methods available to access $_Request, $_Get and $_Post params.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getParam() instead of getParams()`$post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('wedding');`